# How can I post data and get the results from the action page with PHP?

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a web page called ABC. This web page contains a form with just one input, "ID". When you type your ID and submit it, it sends your ID to the server and prints your information on another page.

I know the form page's web address but not the result page's.

I want to post an ID to that form from my script and get the result page into a variable.

The code so far that I tried:

```
function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars=''){

    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        $str = "";
        foreach( $vars as $var => $ele){
            $str .= $var;
            $str .= "=";
            $str .= $ele;
            $str .= "&";
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'asd.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'asd.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50000);

    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
    return $buffer;
}

$loginUrl = 'http://app2.sgk.gov.tr/AylikHesap/servlet/';
$loginFields = array('mernisno'=>'xxx');
$remotePageUrl = 'http://app2.sgk.gov.tr/AylikHesap/servlet/com.sgk.aylikhesap.servlet.EventMultiplexer';  

$login = getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields);

$remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl);

echo $remotePage;
```

It should bring the results. xxx is the ID that I'm talking about.

How do I do that?

Comment: if you have code you tried and failed, then post and ask about that, its more helpfully than how you framed the original question.

Comment: Well, the code is actually working. Finally I found my mistake. It turns out now that there were missing parameters for query to run. Such a fool I am.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) for this

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setUri('http://example.com/login.php');
$client->setParameterPost('ID', 1234);
$response = $client->request('POST');
$result = $response->getBody();
```

If you do not want to use Zend Framework for any reason, you can use [this function](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm).

Comment: Is this necessary to have Zend framework to use Zend_Http_Client class? Can I have it to use manually from source code or something?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for my case. I think I'm mistaken somewhere. Your solution returns 200, it's wonderful, but it does not serve me the result page. It just prints the form page.

Comment: Am I allowed to give the full link and actual info about the problem? Sorry, still trying to get used to stackoverflow :) If I'm allowed, I'll be happily edited my question.

Comment: @gzg: Yes! You're allowed and encouraged to spell out your actual problem, code you used, and anything else you've tried. (Just don't post sensitive data like real passwords.)

Answer (score -1):

[CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

You can retrieve data from a site, but most site's implement some sort of token validation, so in other words you can't post form data across domains.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well enough, are you saying that posting data to a form through different domains is not possible?

Comment: Correct, read the wiki.
Unless the site in question has a public API.

Comment: But I did it before. It just seems this web page resists me.

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood the question, however your original question has been edited. FORM-A = 'mydomain.com' FORM-B = 'yourdomain.com', these cant interact(or at the very least shouldn't).  However you can send data from FORM-A to SITE-B, if SITE-B allows you to through an API, much like twitter or FB.